# When loading my array the values is just the same (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just remade my saving system for my game. To do this I use the Directory.GetDirectories and an array for storing it. The issue is that when it loads, the loading code just loads the same values for how many folders there were. The `string[] profiles` array is different, but not what it loads (`ProfilesData`).

I have also tried to google it, but I guess I search for something wrong. The solution is most likely answered but I am unsure on what to search. I have attempted to debug it myself. I can see that when it is loaded the "value" is the same but I don't know why.

This is the first script that got the array and that should change the path as it does.

```
 //Gets all Directories in the Profiles folder
        string[] profiles = Directory.GetDirectories(Application.persistentDataPath + "/Profiles/");

        for (int i = 0; i < profiles.Length; i++)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("Path", profiles.GetValue(i).ToString());
            AddProfiles();
            Debug.Log(PlayerPrefs.GetString("Path"));
        }
```

This is the loading one that does the UI.

```
 public void AddProfiles()
    {
        ProfilesData data = SaveProfiles.LoadProfiles();

        img = data.profileImage;

        ProfilesUIClone = Instantiate(ProfilesUI) as GameObject;
        ProfilesUIClone.transform.SetParent(wheretomaketheprofileUI.transform.parent);
        Profile = ProfilesUIClone.transform.Find("SelectProfile").transform.Find("Name").GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
        Company = ProfilesUIClone.transform.Find("SelectProfile").transform.Find("Company").GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
        Profile.text = data.profileName;
        Company.text = data.companyName;
        ProfilesUIClone.SetActive(true);
        if (img == 0)
        {
            Image = ProfilesUIClone.transform.Find("SelectProfile").transform.Find("ProfileImage1").GetComponent<Image>();
            Image.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (img == 1)
        {
            Image = ProfilesUIClone.transform.Find("SelectProfile").transform.Find("ProfileImage2").GetComponent<Image>();
            Image.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (img == 2)
        {
            Image = ProfilesUIClone.transform.Find("SelectProfile").transform.Find("ProfileImage3").GetComponent<Image>();
            Image.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
```

And this is the loading script itself.

```
 public static ProfilesData LoadProfiles()
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Profiles/" + PlayerPrefs.GetString("ProfileName") + "/config.dat";
        string path2 = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Path");
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

            ProfilesData data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as ProfilesData;
            stream.Close();

            return data;
        }
        else if (File.Exists(path2))
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(path2, FileMode.Open);

            ProfilesData data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as ProfilesData;
            stream.Close();

            return data;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Save file not found in " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I expect that it loads all the different profiles as it should, but it doesn't it just loads one of the values and puts that for all of the profiles.

Comment: "I can see that when it is loaded the "value" is the same but I don't know why.". What is this value? Also could you try to document your code with comments to make it more readable? It's weird that you set a preference for "Path" but change it multiple times through the for loop. Also, Are you saying that the "ProfileData data" is loading incorrectly? (Thus the fault lies in LoadProfiles())

Comment: I will add comments when I can, thanks for replying. The loading function works, when creating the profiles, but when loading them it doesn't work as it should. I am looping because it is different paths for the different profiles.

Comment: You saying the loading function works but when loading it doesnt work? Are you talking about to different things, could you be a bit more specific and refer to specific functions/variables? (E.g "LoadProfiles()" or "ProfileData data") Thanks.

Comment: Ohh yeah sorry, I mean LoadProfiles() works when you create profiles but when you go to the main menu and it should load them it does load but it is the same value for all of the UI elements but it should be different. And I mean LoadProfiles() and the else if(File.Exists(path2)) That is for the loading for main menu.

Comment: Are the values loaded for all of the menu UI similar to the values of a specific profile? (E.g Always last profile or first). Also can you show how you define ProfilesUIClone and ProfilesUI and finally, when are you calling the above script? Once on start?

Comment: The UI should get the values of one of the profiles Lets say you have Test and Hello, then there should be made 2 UI with one of them that got the values for Test and the other one with the values for Hello, the one that is the newest should be at the top but I haven implemented that yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You're overwriting your data. Also, (maybe) don't use PlayerPrefs for this.

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("Path", profiles.GetValue(i).ToString());
```

You're setting the same key to a new value every time through the loop. If you were to do this instead:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < profiles.Length; i++)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("Path", profiles.GetValue(i).ToString());
        AddProfiles();
    }
    Debug.Log(PlayerPrefs.GetString("Path"));
```

You'd notice that it always prints one thing. The *last* profile.

If you're insistant on making PlayerPrefs do something it was never designed for, then you'd have to change either, the key name (`"Path"`) to something more unique (`"Path"+i`) or otherwise determine which **one** profile you wish to store there. As I am unclear on your use-case, so you will have to figure this out yourself.

Comment: Ok, yeah playerprefs isn't the best, I just used it for testing really and to get it from that file to the other file, thanks for your reply I will look into it. The use case is that it will see how many folders there is in the Profiles folder, then it will load for how many there is there, it got that part correct, just that the UI got the same value for all of them, but it should be different, Would it be possible with an example? and thanks.

Comment: `AddProfiles()` currently adds *one* profile, not all of them. Which it does by calling `LoadProfiles()` (again, only one) which works by querying `PlayerPrefs`. Use a parameter instead? `AddProfile(pathprofiles.GetValue(i).ToString());` There's literally no reason to use a "global" storage system to pass around some data.

Comment: Ok thanks I really appreaciate this, will test it out.